# Elasticsearch не находит по неполному совпадению

Tags: elasticsearch

Нужен полнотекстовый поиск по документам в Elasticsearch. Делаю следующий запрос:

```
{
  "query":{
    "match":{
      "_all":"Дмитр"
    }
  }
}
```

Ничего не находит, но когда полностью прописываю имя

```
{
  "query":{
    "match":{
      "_all":"Дмитрий"
    }
  }
}
```

Находит все записи в которых есть это имя.

Запрос отправляется методом POST на url: `http://127.0.0.1/myindex/people/_search`

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае, скорее всего, в _all попадают токены получаемые стандартным анализатором. Вам необходимо добавить маппинг.
Если нужно находить документы по запросу "Дмитр", возможно для автокомплита, то следует использовать кастомный анализатор с токензатором [edgeNGram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html)

И искать по конкретному полю, где присутствует ФИО. Не засорять _all ("include_in_all": false для данного поля).

Очень мало информации, чтобы дать конкретный пример маппинга и запроса.